# How to pass the selected image of the visitor using Facebook open graph from the previous page

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have the following problem. I hope some one can help me :)

I have a client who has the following URL

http://www.clientwebsite.com/pageA.html

On the above page client has door images which he allows the visitor to select with a radio button. This page i.e. pageA.html does not have any open graph meta tags on it.

Once the visitor selects the door image on pageA.html he is taken to

http://www.clientwebsite.com/pageB.html

Now the client wants to use open graph meta tags on pageB.html which will pass the URL of pageA.html and the selected door image of the visitor from pageA.html to Facebook.

However this is not working as planned. I have tested this using the [Facebook open graph debugger tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) and below are my findings

1. When I pass the og:url meta tag with the URL of pageA.html, Facebook just picks random images from pageA.html and not the one I am passing in the og:image meta tag.
2. When I omit the og:url meta tag, Facebook picks up the image I am passing in the og:image meta tag but it does not know the URL which I need it to use.

Is there a solution to this?

**UPDATE**

Here is the URL in question

http://www.jvd.me.uk/share-test3.html

The above is pageB.html. The URL mentioned in the og:url meta tag is pageA.html

Anyone?

Comment: @asarfaz Quick tip:Its always tough to understand using just words and examples quickly demonstrate what you mean. Thus use pastebin or phpcode.com with your code. Also wondering how are you sending data from one .html page to another html page. A solution could be to pass the URL as well as image from PageA.html(through post or get) to PageB.php(php - so you can capture these values) and set them to the related Facebook variables

Comment: @pal4life I am POSTing the values from pageA.html to pageB.html and filling the open graph meta tags with the values properly. Its just that when some one tries to share it on Facebook, it does not use the og:image tag I am supplying to it rather it uses some random image on pageA.html

Comment: @asarfaz: How are you setting those og:image tags? Can you share the code? Thanks

Comment: @pal4life - Check out the URL I have mentioned above

Comment: _“I am POSTing the values from pageA.html to pageB.html”_ – well, Facebook’s scraper doesn’t POST any data to your page B when it requests it, so this approach is of course bound to fail. Use GET parameters instead – thereby creating two _different_ URLs, that can each be scraped individually.

Comment: @CBroe but I am providing the URL of pageA.html in the open graph meta tags. It should scrape the pageA.html. Strange part is that it's picking up the title and description properly but it's not picking the image even though the image URL is valid and it exists on pageA.html

Comment: Your page A does not contain the relevant Open Graph meta information according to the debug tool.

Comment: @CBroe yes there are no open graph meta tags on pageA.html but then how Facebook is picking up the title and description from the open graph meta tags on pageB.html? It picks up the title and description but then it does not pick the image.

Comment: It doesn’t pick up anything from page B, because in that page your have told FB that the URL where it should look for the data is the URL of page A. And since the latter doesn’t contain specific Open Graph meta information, it just picks up what it can find in the “regular” meta elements and the page title.

Comment: @CBroe ok I will try it out now and let you know of my findings

Comment: @CBroe your assertion was correct. I moved the code to pageA.html and it started to pick the image however I still need a way to pick the selected door color image on pageA.html and I think that may not be possible

Comment: That’s what I already said – it is not possible to have different content based on the user’s choice under the same URL (because when the scraper visits the URL, there is no user to make that choice), so you will need to set up _different_ URLs for your different images. (Using a GET parameter to determine what image to embed would be enough, since different GET parameters make different URLs.)

Comment: @CBroe I want to mark your comment as the answer. If you can answer it then I will mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am POSTing the values from pageA.html to pageB.html

Well, Facebook’s scraper doesn’t POST any data to your page B when it requests it, so this approach is of course bound to fail.

It is not possible to have different content based on the user’s choice under the same URL (because when the scraper visits the URL, there is no user to make that choice), so you will need to set up different URLs for your different images. (Using a GET parameter to determine what image to embed would be enough, since different GET parameters make different URLs.)